# decode protobuf response from Hbase on node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, hbase, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to connect HBase from a node js application

since we are using HBase version 1.0.0 i am using npm module [hbase-rpc-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbase-rpc-client)

i've been able to get the response from hbase, but the response is a protobuf object, and i can't find any way of parsing it back to json

i've tried using [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs), but i still can't understand how to parse it.

my code is as follows:

```
var hbase = require('hbase-rpc-client')
var buffer = require('protobufjs')
var client = hbase({
    zookeeperHosts:['localhost:2181']
})

client.on('error',function(err){console.log(err)})

var Get = new hbase.Get('1')

client.get('testTable',Get,function(err,res){
   if(err){
     console.log(err)
   }
   else{
     var parser = new buffer.DotProto.Parser(res)
   }
})
```

Comment: I think the next step is to invoke the `parse` method of [`DotProto.Parser`](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/blob/master/src/ProtoBuf/DotProto/Parser.js). Did you try it? Any error?

Comment: I've tried using it, but i get an error 'parse error at line 1:unexpected ['   am I building the Parser right?